# Оптимизация списка товаров с помощью Python

Tags: python, yandex-metrika-api

Прошу помочь с решением следующего вопроса.
Из Appmetrica я получаю результаты поисковой выдачи посетителям мобильного приложения: перечень товаров, которые ищут посетители.
Однако одновременно с наименованием товаров, я также получаю все, что ввел пользователь в поисковую строку. Так настроено мобильное приложение разработчиком.

Мне необходимо удалить этот "информационный мусор".
Так, например, посетитель может искать "бинт". Приложение ему выдает в подсказки в поисковой строке по буквам. И, в итоге, после выгрузки из api Appmetrica отчета по нужному мне событию я получаю:

```
б
би
бин
бинт
```

И так далее с другими товарами.
Есть наименования товаров с несколькими словами, я пробовал выдергивать только первое слово

```
data['product_first_word'] = data['product'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[:1]).apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
```

Но, проблема в том, что посетитель может написать тот же "бинт", как "бнт" или "бант", ошибаясь или не попадая в буквы на эл. клавиатуре.

Вопрос в следующем, как мне в перечне товаров, где, помимо прочего, встречаются:

```
б
би
бинт
```

Оставить только слово "бинт" (то есть само целое слово в перечене)?

Список выгружается таким образом, что всегда перед последним словом будут его "побуквенные" разновидности

К сожалению, в регулярных выражениях я не силен. Поэтому даже нет малейших соображений (пример кода) на этот счет.

| товар | количество событий |
| --- | --- |
| б | 23 |
| би | 43 |
| бин | 65 |
| бинт | 76 |
| бинт м | 96 |
| бинт мар | 116 |
| бинт марл | 136 |
| бинт марле | 143 |
| бинт марлев | 152 |
| бинт марлевы | 159 |
| бинт марлевый | 179 |

Comment: Предоставьте воспроизводимый пример данных в вопросе. Т.е. покажите пример (небольшого) датафрейма.

Comment: Добавил, спасибо за совет. Повторюсь, что мне нужно только "бинт марлевый", а остальное - отсечь

Comment: Хотелось бы в виде текста, а не картинки. И в том порядке, в каком вы описали в вопросе, а сейчас у вас наоборот сначала полная форма идёт.

Comment: Доработал в требуемом виде. Прошу помочь с решением вопроса (из примера датафрейма во вложении оставить только "бинт марлевый").

Comment: Если никто не поможет, вечером посмотрю. Работа

Comment: Я понял. Буду признателен.

Comment: Если в поиске есть `бар` и `баран`, то `бар` вам совсем не интересен. Так?

Comment: Не совсем, "бар" будет интересен, если это отдельный запрос от посетителя, введенный в поисковую строку. Мне важно все, что выдает поисковая выдача, но без разбивки итогового запроса на буквы и слоги. Настройка выгрузки из Appmetrica настроена так, что тот запрос ("бар") будет либо перед "б" (открывающего "баран"), либо сращу после "баран". То есть это точно не часть слова "баран"

Comment: Ну вариант сравнивать вхождение предыдущего ввода с текущим, если отличаются на одну последнюю букву, то предыдущий ввод отбрасываем. Если различие больше, то принимаем за результат.

Comment: @AndyPavlov, я так понимаю, что это осуществимо через условные конструкции  и цикл? Я новичок в анализе данных. Вы не могли бы мне помочь с этим (на примере датафрема из того вопроса)?

Comment: А доступ к настройкам Appmetrica у вас есть? Там можно отфильтровать «мусор»

Comment: @СергейКох если вы про Java - то подобных настроек у меня нет и доступа тоже. В разделе настройки вижу событие "Поиск", но не более. Только статус этого события - "собирается"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'product': [
        'б', 'би', 'бин', 'бинт',
        'б', 'ба', 'бар', 'бара', 'баран', 'баранк', 'баранка'
    ]
})
print(df[df['product'] != df['product'].shift(-1).str[:-1]])
```

> ```
> $ python demo.py
> 3      бинт
> 10  баранка
> ```

### Объяснение

Запускаем интерпертатор, создаём фрейм:

```
$ python
Python 3.10.0 (default, Oct 16 2021, 12:17:56) [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
@>>> import pandas as pd
@>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data={'product': ['б', 'би', 'бин', 'бинт', 'б', 'ба', 'бар', 'бара', 'баран', 'баранк', 'баранка']}) 
@>>> df
    product
0         б
1        би
2       бин
3      бинт
4         б
5        ба
6       бар
7      бара
8     баран
9    баранк
10  баранка
```

`next_product` - колонка с продуктами, смещённая на одну запись вверх:

```
@>>> df['next_product'] = df['product'].shift(-1)
@>>> df
    product next_product
0         б           би
1        би          бин
2       бин         бинт
3      бинт            б
4         б           ба
5        ба          бар
6       бар         бара
7      бара        баран
8     баран       баранк
9    баранк      баранка
10  баранка          NaN
```

`complete_request` сравнивает продукт и следующий продукт без последней буквы. Если они не равны, это последний запрос в цепочке:

```
@>>> df['complete_request'] = df['product'] != df['next_product'].str[:-1]
@>>> df
    product next_product  complete_request
0         б           би             False
1        би          бин             False
2       бин         бинт             False
3      бинт            б              True
4         б           ба             False
5        ба          бар             False
6       бар         бара             False
7      бара        баран             False
8     баран       баранк             False
9    баранк      баранка             False
10  баранка          NaN              True
```

По `complete_request` можно отфильтровать фрейм. Останутся только строки с полными запросами:

```
@>>> print(df[df['complete_request']]) 
    product next_product  complete_request
3      бинт            б              True
10  баранка          NaN              True
@>>>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам! Очень помогли!